# i need to change the select menu options,based on another select menus selected value ,inside a table repeater of filament. how can i achieve that?

Tags: laravel, repeater, laravel-filament

```
FilamentFormRepeater::make()->schema([
   Select::make('product_id')->live()
    FilamentTableRepeater::make()->schema([
           Select::make('task_id')->options([....])
    ])
])
```

Now I want to change the select element options of **'task_id'** when a select option is changed in **'product_id'** FilamentFormRepeater.